# How do I iterate inside dependson in ARM Template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have resource which I need to deploy only after group of NIC defined as below is done. How do I iterate with `copy` in dependson[] parent resource (say application gateway)?

```
{
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[concat('Winnic', copyindex())]",
            "location": "[variables('VMResourceGroupLocation')]",
            "copy": {
              "name": "WinnicLoop",
              "count": 3
            },
            "dependsOn": [
              "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                  "name": "ipconfig1",
                  "properties": {
                    "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                    "subnet": {
                      "id": "[variables('DMZsubnetRef')]"
                    }
                }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant do that (iterate inside dependsOn), instead of reference the loop name:

```
"dependsOn": [
    "WinnicLoop"
],
```

that way the resource will depend on the loop (so all resources in the loop)

Comment: This resource loop is defined somewhere else in ARM template, not in the same resource, it will still work? Basically are resource loops global?

Comment: if it's in the same template - it will